# How to listen for events in Python with Infura (2019 year end)?

Tags: python, websocket, ethereum, web3py

web3py 5.3.0 latest doc gives example of eventFilter --

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#event-log-object

```
transfer_filter = my_token_contract.eventFilter('Transfer', 
    {'filter': {'_from': '0xDc3A9Db694BCdd55EBaE4A89B22aC6D12b3F0c24'}})
```

which results in error --

```
*** AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'ContractEvents'
```

While I have raised this issue to web3.py on github --

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1508

Can someone please share working example of listening to Ethereum events in Python **with Infura** websocket, which does not support createFilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to kclowes at web3.py for pointing out that createFilter is indeed supported by Infura *websocket*, for which I've confirmed with my test.

The issue on github has been updated --

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1508